# Spacing around CJK text with ucharclasses package

Tags: spacing, xetex, xecjk, ucharclasses

I'm modifying a .sty file that's used with documents that includes Latin, Arabic and Japanese text intermingled without specific markup.  I am using `xeCJK` to identify the Japanese text and `ucharclasses` to identify the Arabic.  I'm not bound to these, but I need something that switches fonts without markup in the document.

However I've noticed that the `ucharclasses` package causes additional spaces around Japanese text in certain (fairly obscure) circumstances.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}

%\usepackage[Latin,Arabic]{ucharclasses}

\begin{document}
``\texttt{めいじ}''
\end{document}
```

With the `ucharclasses` line commented out I get the first line of the image below, which is what I expect; with it enabled, I get the second line, which has too much space around the hiragana characters:

[image]

The spacing is possibly consistent with xelatex trying to use a double-width monospaced quotation mark, despite it being outwith the `\texttt` block, but that may be a red herring.  However the problem doesn't exhibit without a `\texttt` block.  Obviously in the MWE I can simply drop the `\texttt` as it does nothing; but in the actual documents its part of a more complex macro that I cannot readily drop.

The problem is not specific to the Noto fonts.  If I use Computer Modern as the main font and Takao Mincho as the CJK main font, it still happens.

Is my usage wrong?  I thought adding a `CJK` option to the `ucharclasses` package might fix it, but it seems to break Japanese rendering via `xeCJK` entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd use English quotes here, but it works if you load `ucharclasses` before `xeCJK`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage[Latin,Arabic]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\begin{document}
``\texttt{めいじ}''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marvellous.  For what it's worth, the reason for the Western quotation marks (and also the `\texttt`) is that it's actually a code fragment embedded in and English technical document discussing internationalisation in the code.

Comment: @richard Ah, that makes sense in that context. (I was wondering about the `\texttt`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, while this does fix the Japanese spacing, it breaks the Arabic.  Possibly related to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303938/rtl-support-in-arabic-with-ucharclasses).  I'll wait to see if that question gets an answer before updating this one.